# Bode plot : any good alternative to bodegraph

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm wondering if there is any alternative to "bodegraph" for plotting bode graph with latex.

Especially I would ideally be looking for something easy to run (avoid external computation like with gnuplot for example).

I could use matfig2pgf and export from Matlab but there are some misterious errors coming from this type of plots.

Comment: How about `pgfplots` package with `semilogxaxis` environment? Something along the line of: `\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogxaxis}
...
\end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}`. It can read data from a CSV file or you can enter it into the environment itself, as coordinates.

Comment: For export from Matlab there is also [`matlab2tikz`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz), which gives you a file with a `pgfplots` plot.

Comment: [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/) (Python plotting library) has a [pgf backend](http://matplotlib.org/1.2.0/users/pgf.html?highlight=pgf) as of version 1.2, so it can produce really nice LaTeX-compatible results.  The syntax is very similar to Matlab.  And it's easy to integrate with LaTeX via my [`pythontex`](https://github.com/gpoore/pythontex) package.

Comment: Bodegraph only to shape a curved generated by gnuplot, you can always code from bodegraph format it as you wish.
If I déveleppé Bodegraph is that I wanted to have the layout of Bode diagrams directly from the transfer function without the calculation of the modulus and argument. But it is obvious that I developed for my needs, if you have some ideas to improve it, do not hesitate to let me know.
Can you give an example of what you want to draw
(Sorry for my Google english)